# Using babel-register in my cli npm app works locally, but not globally after publish

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, babel-register

I have developed a javascript CLI app that is using ES2015 code with babel as  compiler. (babel-require hook)

The app works perfectly *locally*, but when I publish on npm, it stops working (babel does not seem to compile the ES2015 files anymore)

**Setup:**

sample `./bootstrap.js` (ES5):

```
require('babel-register');
require('./src/app.js');
```

sample `./src/app.js` (ES2015):

```
import package from 'package';
...
```

sample `./bin/myapp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../bootstrap.js');
```

**Running locally works:**

```
appdir$ ./bin/myapp
I'm running fine!
appdir$
```

**Running globally (after npm install) breaks:**

```
$ sudo npm install -g myapp
└── myapp@0.1.0
$ myapp
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/myapp/src/app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import package from 'package';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/myapp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/myapp/server.js:9:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
```

**Versions:**

```
    ├─┬ babel-register@6.4.3
    │ │ ├─┬ babel-core@6.4.5
    │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
    │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.4.5
    │ │ │ ├── babel-helpers@6.4.5
    │ │ ├── babel-runtime@5.8.35
```

**What I have tried:**

- Adding `ignore: false` in my `.babelrc` file hoping it would enable compilation
- using options in require hook arguments instead of `.babelrc` file

No luck :/

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I figured out what was the issue. I was on the right track thinking there was something forbidding the compilation to happen.

**TL;DR**

`babel-register` hook does not take `ignore` and `only` options from the `.babelrc` file, but it does from its arguments.

The fix in `./bootstrap.js`:

```
require('babel-register')({
  ignore: [],
  only: [/src/],
});
require('./src/app.js');
```

- The `ignore` switch will disable ignoring files which match `node_modules` in their path, which is the case for *every* global module.
- The `only` switch then enables compilation of the files of my project `src` directory.

---

Now, if you're interested, I will describe the steps I took to resolve the issue, because I think I did it right (this time :))...

**Story of the troubleshooting:**

- First, I needed to install `node-debug` commandline tool

  ```
  $ sudo npm install -g node-inspector
  ```
- Then launch my app with it (`--debug-brk` switch asks to stop execution at first line)

  ```
  $ node-debug --debug-brk myapp
  ```
- Open my browser at the local URL provided by `node-debug`, and *voila* see my app code
- Place a breakpoint the line just above the `require('./scr/app.js');` statement
- Click 'play' to continue process execution until that line
- Here starts the tedious task of climbing the error trace using 'step over' and 'step inside' buttons : when the next statement is 'outside' of your error trace (see the one above in the question), I could 'step over'. If the next statement is one of the functions of the trace, 'step in'.
- I then realized, by looking at the 'scope variable' watches, when in the `Object.require.extension` method, in file `babel-register/lib/node.js`, that `ignore` and `only` variables were `undefined`, despite I wanted them to be defined!
- I stepped inside the method `shouldIgnore` of the same file, which confirmed my fears : this function checks for `node_modules` in the path, if `!ignore && !only` and returns `true` (ignore file) if it matches. This is ultimately what caused my ES2015 files to not compile.

  ```
  babel-register/lib/node.js:120:
  function shouldIgnore(filename) {
    if (!ignore && !only) {  // here `ignore` and `only` were null, despite .babelrc values
      return getRelativePath(filename).split(_path2["default"].sep).indexOf("node_modules") >= 0;
    } else {
      return _babelCore.util.shouldIgnore(filename, ignore || [], only);
    }
  }
  ```
- I then guessed that I would have to specify thoses switches directly in `babe-register` arguments.

Comment: wow, thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I had the same error and was looking everywhere with no luck. Using NPM-modules with babel-register is a bit obscure right now so you've helped me out big-time here! Thanks man!!

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! Very hard to find any info on this indeed. I updated the answer to reflect the latest babel api